# Python not available in Ubuntu xenial?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, python, vagrant, ansible

I have just provisioned a Xenial machine with vagrant (based on `xenial64-20180228.1.0-virtualbox.box`). In my host system I have python:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

» python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

But in the provisioned machine,

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial


$ python --version
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Ask your administrator to install one of them

$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

If I install python, it seems fine:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo apt-get install python
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

Why is that? Is it normmal that `python` is not installed in a `xenial` image? Do I need to provision it manually then?

Note: the reason why I need `python`, and not simply `python3`, is that `ansible` explicitly looks for it when deploying to this machine:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu), Ubuntu Xenial ships with Python 3.5.1, which seems atypical when compared to other releases commonly being packaged with 2.X.X.

Refer to the comments on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) question as to why Python 2 is called by the `python` command in Ubuntu. The top answer recommends using an alias to call Python 3 with `python`, as opposed to symlinking and breaking things that use on Python 2. Though I suppose that not having Python 2 installed would defeat the purpose of this precaution, and symlinking might be a viable solution.

Are you sure `ansible` isn't looking for Python 2? [Here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/python_3_support.html) is a pretty recent link to their documentation on upcoming Python 3 support.

Comment: ansible is looking for `python`, and expecting python2 I think. python3 is experimental afaik